# How to set the initial conditions of an astable multivibrator

Tags: bjt, oscillator, flipflop, astable

Consider the following oscillator circuit:

[image: flip flop multivibrator]

I have this running and oscillating at about the frequency I want. However, when first powering it on, one of two things happen:

1. Both LEDs momentarily flash on
2. One LED turns on for slightly longer (or shorter) than the usual phase, and subsequently the oscillation starts at the correct frequency

What I want is for one LED (I don't care which) to turn on for its normal phase, and the oscillation to start basically at t=0.

I'm guessing (with my limited knowledge) that the reason for the observed behaviour is due to the capacitors taking time to charge up, or perhaps containing a different amount of charge to begin with? And if so, what would you suggest in order to obtain the desired behaviour?

I have tried using larger resistors for R3 and R4 (up to 1M) with smaller caps (down to 100nF), with no difference in the result.

For reference, I am using a 9V DC power adapter, with a 100nF capacitor across its terminals. I've left that out of the circuit diagram. Also, I have tested using a 9V battery, with similar results.

Edit: I'm aware this could all be achieved quite easily using a microcontroller. But I'm interested to know if this can be achieved using purely analog electronics.

Comment: Try to add a small capacitor 1nF or in pF across BE junction of a Q1 or Q2.

Comment: If you have this in a situation where you can easily make a modification, perhaps I'd recommend adding a weak pull-down resistor to one of the BJT bases. Maybe 220k or so? I'm just shooting from the hip, though.

Comment: If you want deterministic startup and two LEDs blinking, I suggest a tiny microcontroller. The circuit topology does light up both LEDs briefly at start, and they will be in imbalance until bias points have stabilized, and component tolerances define which LED starts first.

Comment: Do you not think it possible to have deterministic startup using analog electronics?

Comment: I don't have any tiny caps handy, but I did try a 10nF on the BE junction which made no difference. Also, 200k pull-down didn't make a difference either. Too small pull-down just makes the oscillator asymmetric.

Comment: Not automatic but manual: Add a switch between the base and emitter of Q1. Power the circuit up with the switch closed, D2 will light up and stay lit. Open the switch, after a short delay the oscillation starts.

Comment: I'm planning on triggering the circuit via a MOSFET from a RF decoder circuit, so I'm not sure manual is an option :-)

Comment: From another circuit: then use a transistor as the switch, then the switch state can be controlled by a voltage.

Comment: Yep but I want the LEDs to be fully off to begin with, then instantaneously start blinking. Not on, then blinking.

Comment: So you need to use a different circuit. Because even if you use a switch or a MOSFET. The Q2 base current when charging C1 will cause the LED to momentarily flash on

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is not suitable for precise starting but you can try this:

After switch is closed C3 triggers the 2sec pulse to Q3 base what couses the Q1 to be closed (hold) for this interval, so C1 has enough time to be fully charged. After this initial pulse the Q1 is released and able to start "work".

This approach let you to start with nice full period. The schottky is necessary  due to negative voltage appeared on Q1 base during normal operation so Q3_bc junction would be forward biased and affect the period.

A signal Schottky with low reverse current is preffered (necessary).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I suppose if I wanted to reduce the 2s delay, I could use a smaller capacitor for C3 and/or decrease the R7 resistance?

Comment: I'm not sure C4 is necessary in my case. The "switch" will be an N-channel MOSFET on the ground, which is switched from a RF decoder. For all intents and purposes I can assume it won't switch on/off with high frequency.

Comment: Right, in that case (clean edge) the C4 is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Design considerations overlooked

1. The initial conditions will be 0 V across the capacitors and the lowest RC time constant asserts the base first which defines the initial condition for which Vce is saturated on power up.
2. Capacitors tend to have larger tolerances, especially electrolytic, so You never get 50.0 % duty cycle. The power of meta-stable condition is a race for the first VBE to conduct a voltage drop on the collector. You can achieve this by adding a few percent capacitance above the tolerance on the one you want to be slower. or simply shunt the Rc with a larger by the same tolerance stackup to  assert the 1st output to win the startup race.  A few % to 10% is  OK.  Use Darlingtons if you need large Rb/Rc ratios.

- thus all the extraneous circuitry is redundant.

3. When using a supply much greater than 5 V you are exceeding the reverse VBE limits therefore small signal silicon diodes like 1N4148 must be placed before the base.  This will not degrade performance of the negative sawtooth ramp.

### More info

@Audioguru is right on. This is an obsolete design even 50 years ago and the BJT astable is intended only for beginner lessons.

The CMOS Schmitt Astable is far easier to use with very high input Z and comes in packages of 6. It has a driver impedance of about 40 ~ 50 Ohms typ. @ 5V so you can easily drive ultrabright LEDs @ 5mA or more if necessary. All you need is an RC for oscillation and a series R for each   Deduct 40~50 Ohms from your R calculation for current to emulate the 74HC series @ 5V

https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT14.pdf

[It doesn't get any simpler than this.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YwrAbPEB2S8CMBOZAOBtkAmbMAkWCWcygUwFp10AodWdEO%20AFg4GZeknHnUJcIhEBKqwmAYz6EIDLsN6KF4EOnrJJkHMhWZeOeHjCF0PMNDDMA7gqWKcTjletNHDeM7CufJQ9JJgAnNxF-d18OF010GESYFhxeWJwA4IZMCWVrKCp0NCReSH5ycCYAcwi1NwgGsI4uTJUtQWDxRSYAJXb3NvQO5CQGkDEKsZsZGqGOTCQ5uhbNMBZ4XJW893Rc4IkAExoAMwBDAFcAGwAXOkuaA61VqDt1vd35wS2FyRAjs6ut3uj3Y7Aa0GY4WWAR%20Sx%20XTW3iGQTagU%20lShWD2qPQIwG%20TEXmiKOEjGxPAcxPRDA%20dFhRIYeO2aO2iPSrVU6lZTAA9iA0tx4rxYFxeDwqDYwVomEA)

[image]

However 1st time constant is longer to reach the upper threshold from the Vcap =0V then it oscillates on the input from 1/3 to 2/3 of Vdd.  Use a large R for negative feedback on the inverter to keep it self biased as long as it is << than the leakage current of the e-cap.

For much slower clocks. The CD4060 binary clock is another favorite 50 yr old design that always performs but with high output resistance @ 5V so a 74HC series is needed to buffer the LED unless 2mA is adequate.

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to minimise the capacitor values for that reason. If there is a current initially across the LEDs, I can tolerate it if it's less than 1ms, but not if it's perceptible. I don't need an exact 50% duty cycle.

Comment: Still Trying? ...

Comment: Yep, between work commitments :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need one of the LEDs to be shorted/bypassed for a short duration at startup so that it doesn't light up for that time. A transistor with a resistor and capacitor can be used to do it. I dont think you'll also need a relay.
If you need both LEDs to be off, you need two such circuits. But then, it'll look like nothing works for a short duration.[image]

Comment: Thanks - this seems a bit incomplete though. The LED would only need to be bypassed once, which I'm not sure of a good way of doing as described. A circuit diagram would be really useful :)

Comment: Added a hand drawn picture with my phone. The change is in the right part of your circuit. I haven't tried it. You'll have to play with the RC values some. The idea is that at startup, one of the LEDs will be bypassed by the transistor which will stay on for a bit because of the capacitor charging. You should add a resistor (470?) at the base of the transistor to prevent the inrush current thru the transistor base at start. I forgot to put that in.

Comment: Will try this on the weekend :)

Comment: I've tried this circuit on a breadboard and it results in some interesting behaviour when the power is switched off. I think I concur with the other posts now that I really need to use a more modern IC.

Comment: The 50 year old 555 IC will work fine too !

Comment: I've had a go and can't get the 555 to work reliably. Could be that I have dud models, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the 50 years old circuit that has many parts and a few problems, why not make a more modern circuit like this:

[image: CD4047]

Comment: I have a few discrete parts lying around and would rather avoid buying a particular IC for such a simple job, if possible.

Comment: Incidentally, there's also the 50 year old chip called 555 which can be used ! Yes. That chip is 50 year old this year !!!

Comment: I wanted to avoid using the dreaded 555, although might resort to that since I do have a few...

Comment: I'm tempted to do this.

Comment: @Audioguru I've attempted this circuit, and I obtain the square wave from pin 13, but pins 10 and 11 always settle into a stable state, with one off and the other on.

Comment: Pin 13 of a CD4047 is a rectangular waveform, not a perfect squarewave. The IC uses a digital divider to produce perfect squarewaves at pin 10 and pin 11. The signals at pin 10 and pin 11 are at half the frequency of the signal at pin 13. Please post the schematic and parts values (including power supply voltage and load resistance) of your circuit that did not work.

Comment: The one I tried last is here: https://diyodemag.com/_images/5fbe3f6ec672e0d86dd9f852,816,544 components include: 10uF cap / 10k resistor on pin 2, 470 ohm resistors in front of each LED, 9V battery for supply

Comment: Someone else had the exact same problem, first comment here: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/4047-astable-multivibrator-circuit.php nobody replied